# Error: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. Using ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

ERROR in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 2413:45
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2413:45)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
intent: renderingIntent,
renderInteractiveForms: renderInteractiveForms === true,
annotationStorage: annotationStorage?.getAll() || null
});
}
ERROR in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js 895:20
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (895:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
this._on(eventName, listener, {
external: true,
once: options?.once
});
}

Comment: same issue using webpak v4 & react, have you got any answer for this?